# Adding two column's data into one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two columns in my report as below

```
ABC    XYZ
-------------
NULL   1
NULL   NULL
5      NULL 
4      8
NULL   1
8     NULL
```

I would like to add these two values and need final result as below

```
1
NULL
5
12
1
8
```

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

I think this is what you want.

```
Select 
      Case WHEN (ABC is null AND XYZ is null) THEN NULL 
           ELSE (Coalesce(ABC,0) + Coalesce(XYZ,0)) END as [sum]
from table
```

Answer (score 3):

use `ISNULL()` to check for NULL value before addition

```
NULLIF(ISNULL(ABC, 0) + ISNULL(XYZ, 0), 0)
```

Comment: What if there would be a row with opposite values, such as `1` and `-1`?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ISNULL(ABC, 0) + ISNULL(XYZ , 0) AS SUM FROM  table ;
```

This works for MS Sql Server

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (ABC INT, XYZ INT);

INSERT INTO @Table
VALUES (NULL, 1)
, (NULL, NULL)
, (5, NULL)
, (4, 8)
, (NULL, 1)
, (8, NULL);

SELECT  ABC
,       XYZ
,       CASE WHEN   ABC IS NULL
              AND   XYZ IS NULL THEN NULL
             ELSE ISNULL(ABC, 0) + ISNULL(XYZ, 0)
        END AS Result
  FROM  @Table;
```

That should do it for you.

Comment: It also helpful for the other users here to post code for your source tables.  That way we can cut and paste a data set directly into an editor. As your questions become more complicated, you'll find you get far more responses that way.